# Encrypt AES/CBC/PKCS7Padding with Dart (works on Kotlin)

Tags: flutter, kotlin, dart, encryption

I'm new in Dart and I'm trying to rewrite my kotlin LoginData encryption.
I tried to do this with package:encrypt/encrypt.dart

Below you can find my kotlin code which works:

```
data class LoginData(
    val login: String,
    val password: String
)
```

```
data class LoginBody(
    val encrypted: String,
    val publicToken: String
)
```

```
    fun encryptLoginData(loginData: LoginData): LoginBody {
        val jsonLoginData: String = Gson().toJson(loginData)

        val iv: ByteArray = generateIv()
        val publicToken =
            String(Base64.encode(iv, DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE), StandardCharsets.UTF_8)

        val encryptedLoginData: String = encrypt(jsonLoginData, iv)
        val encryptedLoginDataBase64Encoded =
            String(
                Base64.encode(encryptedLoginData.toByteArray(), DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE),
                Charset.defaultCharset()
            )

        return LoginBody(encryptedLoginDataBase64Encoded, publicToken)
    }
```

```
    private fun generateIv(): ByteArray {
        val iv = ByteArray(16)
        SecureRandom().nextBytes(iv)
        return iv
    }
```

```
    private fun initCipher(iv: ByteArray): Cipher {
        val cipher: Cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS7Padding")
        val secretKeySpec = SecretKeySpec(Constants.PRIVATE_KEY.toByteArray(), 0, 32, "AES")
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec, IvParameterSpec(iv))
        return cipher
    }
```

```
    private fun encrypt(stringToEncrypt: String, iv: ByteArray): String {
        val encrypted: ByteArray =
            initCipher(iv).doFinal(stringToEncrypt.toByteArray(Charsets.UTF_8))
        return String(Base64.encode(encrypted, DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE))
    }
```

DONE WITH FOLLOWING CODE:
final encryptedLoginData = encrypter.encrypt(json, iv: iv).base64;
final encoded = base64.encode(utf8.encode(encryptedLoginData));

Comment: How do you import the library to run the Kotlin code above? I have tried many iterations of implementations (via the build.gradle) & imports in the script. Nothing I have tried works.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use:

```
dependencies:
  pointycastle: ^2.0.0
  encrypt: ^4.1.0
```

Here after two simple methods to encrypt/decrypt a plain message:

```
  String encrypt(String plainText) {
    final key = Key.fromUtf8(password);
    final iv = IV.fromLength(16);
    final encrypter = Encrypter(AES(key));
    final encrypted = encrypter.encrypt(plainText, iv: iv);
    return encrypted.base64;
  }

  String decrypt(String encrypted) {
    final key = Key.fromUtf8(password);
    final iv = IV.fromLength(16);
    final encrypter = Encrypter(AES(key));
    final decrypted = encrypter.decrypt64(encrypted, iv: iv);
    return decrypted;
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for reply.
My private key is like 
"ksjdg*&%\$dfgh\"{#@!vcfkslc,.a/dcfxcsw345,45654gfdsgtrasd;fsdjf]}{O0-xfvbgasdh="

When I do with your method I got error: 

Invalid argument(s): Key length must be 128/192/256 bits.


I can not change this key.

Below you can see how I did it in Kotlin:
val secretKeySpec = SecretKeySpec(Constants.PRIVATE_KEY.toByteArray(), 0, 32, "AES")

Comment: try this : final encrypter = Encrypter(AES(key, mode: AESMode.cbc));

Comment: I manually deleted the excessive number of characters from the private key (currently 32 characters) and it still works on android. The problem is my encrypted on android is 90 characters and my encrypted on flutter is 64.
I Think it's something with base64 encoding. 

Below you can see what I do with encrypted on Android:


        val encryptedLoginDataBase64Encoded =
            String(
                Base64.encode(encryptedLoginData.toByteArray(), DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE),
                Charset.defaultCharset()
            )

Comment: I did it! 

    final encryptedLoginData = encrypter.encrypt(json, iv: iv).base64;
    final encoded = base64.encode(utf8.encode(encryptedLoginData));